# Prove that $\lambda_1 x_1 + \lambda_2 x_2 \in S$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $S \subseteq V$ be a absolutely convex set, where $V$ is a vector space over $K$. Then show that

$\forall x_1, x_2 \in S$ and $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in K$ such that $|\lambda_1|+ |\lambda_2| \leq 1$ then $\lambda_1 x_1 + \lambda_2 x_2 \in S$

Can some one help me out.

Def: A set $S$ absolutely convex set if

1) $S$ is convex 
2) $S$ is balanced i.e., $ \forall x\in S$ and $\alpha \in K$ such that $|\alpha| \leq 1$ then $\alpha x \in S$.

Comment: What is the definition of convex, where $K$ is any field, or did you mean $K=\Bbb R$.

Comment: Yes here $K = \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  $\alpha=\lambda_1+\lambda_2\neq 0$, put  and $\beta_1=\dfrac{\lambda}{\alpha}$ and $\beta_2=\dfrac{\lambda_2}{\alpha}$, you have  $\beta_1+\beta_2=1$, then $y=\beta_1 x_1+\beta_2x_2\in S$ , and $\lambda_1x_1+\lambda_2x_2=\alpha y\in S$ (because $|\alpha|\leq 1$), if $\alpha=0$ try ...
. unless I'm mistaken

Comment: Don't forget the cases where one or both $\lambda_{j}$ are negative.

Comment: For example if $\lambda_1\leq 0$, then you can change $\lambda_1$ by $-\lambda_1$ and remark that $-x_1\in S$ (because $|-1|\leq 1$).

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted you to mention those cases for the OP.